# Native iPhone app: Running JavaScript code from Objective-C on enterForeground event

Tags: javascript, iphone, objective-c

I want to run some JavaScript code when my iPhone app enters foreground.
So I did this:

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {
    NSLog(@"1");

    [self.viewController.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.alert('ok');"];

    NSLog(@"2");    
}
```

When I run it and switch the app from back- to foreground, the logs just display "1" but not "2" and I get no alert message.

What's going on?

Ps.: I use Phonegap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the cause for the problem. self.viewController.webView in AppDelegate.m seems to be the wrong reference.
I guess it's a Phonegap issue.

So, I worked around this by simply using Phonegap's onResume event. http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_events_events.md.html#resume

That did the trick.